# My sprites are being deleted when another sprite is added in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Ok I am a complete noob to pygame and programming in general. However I have been working on a game where the player falls and dodges objects. The idea is that the player remains within the top 1/4 of the screen and everything scrolls upwards to give the illusion of moving. This works fine however the code below is where I try and get another wall to spawn. This should work by deleting the sprite when it goes off the screen and spawning a new sprite when the image starts to go off the screen. The -2 is how far it should cross until another is spawned and my logic was to check the size of the group. While it only contained one it would iterate through the next section of code defining a new wall sprite identical to the old one but positioned below it. However this causes the program to crash probably because the old sprite is deleted causing an infinite loop. So if this is true how do you define a new sprite with the same attribute whilst not killing the other?

Also I realised that the code wont even work multiple times because I used "left_wall" which wont be defined after its been deleted so I tried using "wall" as I iterate through the group defining each sprite as wall in the for loop so every time a new wall is added it should be defined as wall so that I works infinitely. however I this error message AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'wall'. So at this moment I am stuck, not really knowing what to do next.

edit: I forgot to take off "self" when using "wall" which was the cause of the attribute error however it is still crashing like I mentioned in the first paragraph which is probably due to the old sprite being deleted.

sorry if this is confusing or not a properly structured question (like I said, I am a noob).

```
 for wall in self.left_wall_sprite:
            wall.rect.y -= self.player.vel.y
            if wall.rect.bottom < 0:           # move left wall
                wall.kill()
            if wall.rect.top == -2:    # a new wall needs to be spawned


                while len(self.left_wall_sprite) < 2:

                    self.new_left_wall = self.left_wall
                    self.new_left_wall.rect.top = self.left_wall.rect.bottom
                    self.all_sprites.add(self.new_left_wall)
                    self.left_wall_sprite.add(self.new_left_wall) # add the new sprite to the wall group so that it runs through the same cycle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only this part of the code, it is hard to tell for sure what is going on - but what can be detected is that you create a new wall section, but do not "leave things as you found them" - so, that the code will still try to move the old wall.

If you really need to create a new sprite, go all the way: once the condition is met for the change:

1. get  a reference to the old wall
2. remove the old wall from all groups (the `.kill` method)
3. create a new wall (create a new instance - you are just making an
   assigment to an existing instance).
4. insert the new instance in all relevant groups.

As the code is, you are just pointing to the same wall object (self.left_wall) so that "self.let_wall" and "self.new_let_wall" are just references to the samething, and when you change a parameter (like rect.top) in one side, you can see the same change in the other.

Without the code for the class of your wall objects, one can't now if everything is set for correctly creating a new instance, but that could typically be done  by `self.left_wall = Wall((wall.rect.bottom, wall.rect.left, wall.rect.width, wall.rect.height))` (if your class's `__init__` will take a rect as first parameter). This replaces the old `self.rect_wall` (which should have a reference on the `wall` variable yet) - you then just add it to the new groups.

But it looks like you can just reuse the same sprite - so, jsut update the top coordinate as you are doing -no need to fiddle with group containment or anythng:

```
  if wall.rect.bottom <= 0:   
        wall.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom  # or "0" at once
```